# Jhipster migration from Mysql database to Cassandra

Tags: jhipster

I have created an application from jhipster which is microservice based. I have gateway registry and application which is running on MySql database. Now I want to migrate from MySQL to Cassandra database. Can you please let me know the changes I need to make in java/class files and list of file. So far I made some changes like application-dev yml. I have this application on hibernate, ehcache etc. Changed the class name in cacheconfiguration.java. Please let me know anyother changes required to run on database.

Regards
Satyanvesh

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same Java POJO classes to annotate with Spring-Cassandra or datastax Cassandra annotations. If you want to migrate your data as well export your data tables as csv from MySQL and use the COPY command in cql to copy from csv to Cassandra.